# Set a fixed value for a Progress Bar

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I'm developing an application which will use a Progress Bar.

The problem is that I don't want to use the method `setProgressBar()`, just because I want to regulate the loading amount manually.

In fact when I use, for instance, `setProgress(20)`, the bar will keep updating by 20 every time.

I mean, I need to call a kind of "set" method which take an input as parameter and set the fixed amount on the progress bar without change it time after time.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation states:

> setProgress(int progress)
>
> Set the current progress to the specified value.

Meaning you can set the progress of the progressbar to the fixed value you want. The only thing you need to do is call it on the right time.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not explain very well. Actually, when I call setProgress(5) the bar keep increase its loading amount by 5 every time. What I need is to simply set to 5 the progress bar loading amount. Is it clear?

Comment: Isn't you setProgress()-method not called multiple times?

Comment: I only call setProgress() when an accelerometer event occurs, but also if I use setProgress(0) before it (trying to reset the bar), it does not work at all!

Comment: I found a very hidden error in my code, there were another setProgress() in it. The code is very long so it was drivin' me crazy. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should write like this!

```
ProgressDialog progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressdialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressdialog.setCancelable(false);
progressdialog.show();
```

Finally, you should set the progress wtih this method

```
progressdialog.setProgress(1);
```